# How to define the culture for an application domain in .NET 4.5

Tags: appdomain, culture, .net-4.5

According to [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171868%28v=vs.110%29.aspx), .NET 4.5 introduces the *"ability to define the culture for an application domain"*. This is a feature I wanted for a long time, because without it you need to set the culture explicitly for each new thread if you don't want to use the system culture.

However, when I looked through the documentation I couldn't find any relevant property or method in `AppDomain` or `AppDomainSetup`.

Did someone manage to make it work? What API did you use?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You set the culture on static properties on [`CultureInfo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) class.

Have a look at [`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentCulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx) and 
[`CultureInfo.DefaultThreadCurrentUICulture`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.cultureinfo.defaultthreadcurrentuiculture%28v=VS.110%29.aspx)